# Double quotes not rendered correctly in XeLaTeX for Bengali language

Tags: xetex, csquotes

Please see the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

% LaTeX style quotes
``বাংলা ভাষা''

% Double quotes
"বাংলা ভাষা"

% Using package, produces incorrect results
\enquote{বাংলা ভাষা}

% English LaTeX style quotes
\textenglish{``Bengali Language''}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The double quotes in Bengali are either rendered incorrectly
or not rendered at all.

The ones in English work fine.

How do I improve the scenario?

I am not particularly enthusiastic about the `\enquote` solution. This is going to be cumbersome for my large document. If possible,  I would like to stick the LaTeX style double single quotes.

(The font used can be found [here.](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf))

**EDIT 1**
As suggested in a comment, I moved the `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` line before the `\newfontfamily\bengalifont` lines. Unfortunately, that produced an output like the following.

[image]

(I also removed the `csquotes` parts since these are not relevant.)

There was not any warning message regarding missing ligatures or some such.

Comment: Move `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` before loading the Bengali fonts.

Comment: @egreg That did not work, please see my edits.

Comment: That means that the font SolaimanLipi doesn't have the quotes.

Comment: @egreg What is the best possible (please read painless) approach in that scenario?

Comment: Using a better font? But does Bengali use English style quotes to begin with?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same as those show for English example.

Comment: For another smaller task, I used a macro like this, `\long\def\benquote#1{\textenglish{``}#1\textenglish{''}}`. But that is bit cumbersome for the large project I am working on.

Comment: So I find it strange that a Bengali font hasn't them.

Comment: No, there are other Unicode fonts which have these, but the font in question is particularly suited for the task at hand.

Comment: Then do `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{“}{\textenglish{“}}\newunicodechar{”}{\textenglish{”}}` and use the “real quotes” `“` `”` in the document.

Comment: Works like a charm. Want to convert your comment to a complete answer with relevant explanations which I would love to accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first of all move the `\defaultfontfeatures` declaration before loading fonts for which you want that `Ligatures=TeX` apply.

However, if the font hasn't the required glyphs, you can use `newunicodechar`. You can also define a Bengali quote style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}

\newfontfamily\bengalifont{SolaimanLipi}[
  Script=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold=4.0,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.4,
]

\setotherlanguage{english}
% Times New Roman used
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\testchar}[1]{\iffontchar\font`#1\relax#1\else\textenglish{#1}\fi}
\newunicodechar{“}{\testchar{“}}
\newunicodechar{”}{\testchar{”}}
\newunicodechar{‘}{\testchar{‘}}
\newunicodechar{’}{\testchar{’}}

\DeclareQuoteAlias{english}{bengali} % share the English style

\begin{document}

“বাংলা ভাষা”

\enquote{বাংলা ভাষা}

% English LaTeX style quotes
\textenglish{``Bengali Language''}

\textenglish{“Bengali Language”}

\end{document}
```

You need to use `“` and `”`, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment with a picture.

Looking at the Latin side of the font, you may need to add in other glyphs. `newunicodechar` is probably the best way to do that.

Depending on what you need to do, and what you are used to, and how much (if any) keyboard switching is involved, you can also define commands in Bangla, like `\let\ৡ\section` and
`\let\হ\tableofcontents`, and then use them as normal, `\হ` and `\ৡ{কাকীকৌ}`.

Note that SolaimanLipi font has a bold version.

I tried an experiment, using random letters:

[image: dashes quotes and bold]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\fpunct{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fdev{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand\bqql{{\fpunct “\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bqqr{{\fpunct\thinspace ”}}
\newcommand\bql{{\fpunct ‘\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bqr{{\fpunct\thinspace ’}}
\newcommand\bc{{\fpunct ,}}
\newcommand\bend{{\fpunct\textendash\ }}
\newcommand\bemd{{\fpunct\textemdash\  }}
\newcommand\bdanda{{\fdev ।\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bddanda{{\fdev ॥\thinspace}}

\let\ৡ\section
\let\হ\tableofcontents
\let\ন\bend
\let\ম\bemd
\let\ড\bdanda
\let\ডড\bddanda

\begin{document}
{\fpunct\small Just to try out the mechanics of the process:}

\হ
\vspace{1ex}
\hrule
\vspace{1ex}

\ৡ{রষেধৗস}
অকথষোধৈঘৄঙী \ন অকথষো \bqql ধৈঘৄঙী\bqqr\  অকথষো \ম\bql ধৈ\bqr\ \ম ঘৄঙী \ড

\noindent\textbf{অকথষোধৈঘৄঙী \ন অকথষো \bqql ধৈঘৄঙী\bqqr\  অকথষো \ম\bql ধৈ\bqr\ \ম ঘৄঙী \ড}
\ৡ{কাকীকৌ}
কাকীকৌ \ড \\
কাকীকৌ \ডড
\end{document}
```

**Correction**:

Package commands looking for `\section` and so on, for example like in `titletoc`, won't find `\ৡ`, so one way is to patch everything, or, alternatively, just keep using `\section` and swap keyboards as usual.

For example, when adding shading to section numbers in the table of contents:

[image: tikz section numbers]

MWE2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\fpunct{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fdev{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand\bqql{{\fpunct “\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bqqr{{\fpunct\thinspace ”}}
\newcommand\bql{{\fpunct ‘\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bqr{{\fpunct\thinspace ’}}
\newcommand\bc{{\fpunct ,}}
\newcommand\bend{{\fpunct\textendash\ }}
\newcommand\bemd{{\fpunct\textemdash\  }}
\newcommand\bdanda{{\fdev ।\thinspace}}
\newcommand\bddanda{{\fdev ॥\thinspace}}

\let\ৡ\section
\let\হ\tableofcontents
\let\ন\bend
\let\ম\bemd
\let\ড\bdanda
\let\ডড\bddanda

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\newcommand\bframe[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [shade,
      top color=red!40,
      bottom color=violet!5,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,violet}
    ] {#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\bframe{\thesection}}{0.75em}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[1em]%left
{}%abovecode
{\bframe{\thecontentslabel}\hspace{0.75em}}%numbered format
{\huge}%numberless format
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage} % page number
[]%belowcode

\begin{document}

\হ
\vspace{1ex}
\hrule
\vspace{1ex}

\section{রষেধৗস}
অকথষোধৈঘৄঙী \ন অকথষো \bqql ধৈঘৄঙী\bqqr\  অকথষো \ম\bql ধৈ\bqr\ \ম ঘৄঙী \ড

\noindent\textbf{অকথষোধৈঘৄঙী \ন অকথষো \bqql ধৈঘৄঙী\bqqr\  অকথষো \ম\bql 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [shade,
      top color=blue!40,
      bottom color=blue!5,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] {ধৈ};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\bqr\ \ম ঘৄঙী \ড}
\section{কাকীকৌ}
কাকীকৌ \ড \\
কাকীকৌ \ডড
\end{document}
```